# high watermark, level and round

Tags: tenderbake

What's a correct tenderbake implementation of a high watermark to prevent slashing?

Assuming

- current high watermark for attestation is at level L and round R
- signature for attestation is requested for a level l and round r

Is the below pseudocode correct?

```
if (l < L) or (l == L and r <= R)
  reject
else
  R = r
  L = l
  sign
```

Or is it possible to go back in levels?

For example, if I have only signed round 0 for level 6, and only round 0 for level 7, can I subsequently sign round 1 of level 6? Doing so would not make me equivocate, but is this scenario possible at all in tenderbake and shall my signer permit it?

Note that I am using attestation as an example, but I am maintaining a separate high watermark for each operation type (bake, preattest, attest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pseudocode is correct, and it's not allowed to go back in levels. A delegate injects a block/(pre)attestation at level `n` only if it has seen an attestation quorum for level `n-1`, so the payload at level `n-1` is finalized, there is no need to